# How to use Win32 icons

Tags: c#, winapi

How can I use the Win32 icons like open icon, new file icon, and save icon. Do I have to download them as images? Or are the images in a dll? Maybe `System.Windows.Shell`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows standard icons can be found here:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary\1033\VS2008ImageLibrary.zip`

After you install Visual Studio 2008 (both pro or the free express)

Or for VS2005
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\VS2005ImageLibrary\VS2005ImageLibrary.zip`

**Edit:**
Found [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images), it's a good reference if you want other free icons.